# Checar categoria escolhidas

Tags: php, foreach

Preciso checar se as categorias escolhidas pelo usuário existe nas categorias sugeridas pelo sistema php

Consegui gravar no array as categorias escolhidas pelo usuário e também categorias sugeridas pelo sistema.

```
foreach($array_id_categoria_escolhida as $value_as){
   echo $value_as;
}

echo " ";

foreach($array_categoria_sugerida as $value_ass){
   echo $value_ass;
}
```

Como eu posso juntar esses dois foreach e checar se o usuário selecionou as categorias sugeridas pelo sistema?

Answer (score 0):

A lógica é mais ou menos essa, não testei o código mas é provável que funcione

```
foreach($array_categoria_sugerida as $value_ass){

    $resul = array_search($value_ass, $array_id_categoria_escolhida);

if ($resul != false){

    $iguais[] = $resul;

  }
}

if(isset($iguais)) {
    foreach($iguais as $valor) {
        $res[] = $array_id_categoria_escolhida[$valor];
    }
}

//todas que batem
var_dump($res);
```

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "4" } o resultado foi esse

Comment: no teste que fiz aqui era pra retornar apenas um id_categoria, pois no caso esta faltando apenas uma categoria da lista de sugestão

Comment: o resultado do meu foreach eh assim 

escolhidas 214 
sugeridas 1234

Comment: no meu exemplo varri o array 'escolhidos' passando valor por valor do array 'sugeridos', os valores que fosse igual automaticamente ele escolheu com base nas sujestões, e armazenei-os em $res